# AppData locations in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I get locations for "Local" and "Roaming" inside "AppData" folder through Unity?
I am able to get "LocalLow" directory using the code below, how do I get the rest two of them?

```
string m_Path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath)

Keep in mind that these special folders are a Windows concept. If your application is supposed to be run on a non-Windows platform, you should verify which directories these special folders are mapped to on the platform(s) of interest.